# ODataClient with HttpClient Credentials

Tags: c#, .net-core, odata, httpclient

I want to read OData service via `Microsoft.OData.Client`. The service requires a login, a password, and an API key. I have problems with SSL verification.

> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceTransportException: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
>
> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure ...

When I read data using a `HttpClient`, where I provide login, password and API key, in http headers, everything is ok.

Is there a way to bridge OData to use typed `HttpClient`, which I configure at startup in `Program.cs`?

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<EpicorApiClient>((serviceProvider, httpClient) =>
    {
        var settings = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ErpApiConfiguration>>().Value;

        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(settings.Url);
        var base64EncodedAuthenticationString = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(settings.Login + ":" + settings.Password));
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedAuthenticationString);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", settings.ApiKey);
    })


[EnableQuery]
protected async Task<LoadResult> ReadEpicorData<T>(string method, DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions) where T : class
{
    try
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        var context = new DataServiceContext(_httpClient.BaseAddress, ODataProtocolVersion.V4);
        var ss = context.CreateQuery<T>("Parts");
        //EpicorUtils.SetCertificatePolicy();

        var result = DataSourceLoader.Load(ss, loadOptions);

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while reading data, EPICOR DAO, {type}, {method} ", typeof(T), method);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Pure `HttpClient` works ok, but I would like to use `ODataClient` and its possibilities. I don't want to use `Simple.OData.Client`, because I need Queryable context. I want to provide result to front which I plan with Devextreme controls.

Please help, I read all the internet ;)